# How do I get a derivative of the field inside of the path integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, path-integral, functional-derivatives

I am trying to find the 3-gluon vertex rule in QCD by finding the amplitude of a 1-2 gluon scattering process. I want to find the generating functional of the interaction by taking the functional without the interaction and finding the first order correction. I try writing $$ Z[J] = \int DA \: e^{iS[A]+i \int d^{4}x \, J \, A} \sim e^{i S_{interaction}[\frac{\delta}{i\delta J}]}\int DA \: e^{iS_0[A]+i \int d^{4}x \,J \, A}. $$

The problem I am having is the specific form of the 3-gluon interaction, $$\mathcal{L}_{3} \sim A^2 \partial A.$$ Getting the $A$s into the path integral is easy, just take a functional derivative, but I don't know how to get the $\partial A$ term into the path integral.

Comment: I don't have knowledge about details of strong interactions but I can think of a way mathematically, del(e^(iSA))= e^(iSA) (iA del(S)+ iS del(A)).

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov The problem is then how do i bring down $A(k)$ and that requires an inverse fourier transform which is just running in circles, right?

Comment: Just use the differential operator on the functional derivative...

Answer (score 1):

We are using the formula
$$ F[\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta J}]\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar} \int\!d^dx~J(x)\phi(x)\right]~=~F[\phi]\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar} \int\!d^dx~J(x)\phi(x)\right].$$

*Example:* A derivative action term of the form
$$\int\!d^dx~\phi(x)^n(\partial_x\phi(x))^m$$
transforms into
$$\int\!d^dx~\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta J(x)}\right)^n\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_x\frac{\delta}{\delta J(x)}\right)^m.$$

Comment: If I took this approach with an interaction term that looks something like $A^2 \, \partial A \, \partial A$ then I would end up with a derivative term like $A^{3} \, \partial ^{2} A$ that I dont want though, right? What would I do in that situation?

Comment: I updated the answer.